# Using pinvoke to get access to system objects and query about a process

Tags: c#, .net, performance, process, pinvoke

while I learn about p/invoke I could see some noticeable performance gains compared to using .net methods that's because it is querying the information via systems dlls

For instance by importing the dll in this code

```
[DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetProcessMemoryInfo(IntPtr hProcess, out PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS Memcounters, int size);
```

I could get access to information regarding the process in question so I could question all I need to know about it's memory usage.

But as I could notes in that link The [Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394277%28VS.85%29.aspx) and the [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it seems that I could access a class that is not used by P/invoke and query very specific info.

```
uint64 IODataOperationsPerSec;
uint64 IOOtherOperationsPerSec;
uint64 IOReadBytesPerSec;
uint64 IOReadOperationsPerSec;
uint64 IOWriteBytesPerSec;
uint64 IOWriteOperationsPerSec;
uint64 IODataBytesPerSec;
uint64 IOOtherBytesPerSec;

uint32 PageFaultsPerSec;
uint64 PageFileBytes;
uint64 PageFileBytesPeak;
```

as you could see, there is also separated functions for both 32bit / 64bit processes

So here I could know for sure, that I am getting exactly what I need to query and then I noticed that I could get all I need through that class, which I could find in .net an equivalent one I guess (wmi) but I was searching for exactly that, a class that for 1, I will surely know that I am querying correctly 32bit tasks and 64bit tasks and 2 the counters are all together in one class, `I/O` , `CPU Time`, `Memory usage` and the performance issue that it is quite a notisble performance gain compared to using the .net approach .

So **the question is**:

how do I get access to that class via using a method like P/invoke and not own .net classes ?

And actually the most interesting link I have found regarding counters for managed .net in details is [This Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647791.aspx) , I guess that is the equivalent to the win32 links above.

Comment: You don't use pinvoke that get that info, you use the classes in the System.Management namespace.  Thin wrappers for WMI.  Use [this utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to experiment, also generates the C# code you need.  Any perf benefit you'd think you see from pinvoke only exists in your imagination.

Comment: Concur with @HansPassant - the WMI wrapper in the `System.Management` namespace is the way to go here.

Comment: @JerKimball thanks for the information i will check that option i guess i already figured its not the way to go with pInvoke ..

Answer (score 0):

Last time I worked with P/Invoke, it was much easier to accomplish in a managed C++ library, and then import that into my c# app. If you know C++, you will save yourself a lot of trouble when it comes to those kinds of operations.